# Is there any reference about backpropagation of the Transformer's multi-head layer?

Tags: backpropagation, transformers

Is there any reference about backpropagation of the Transformer's multi-head layer or multi-head attention (MHA)? I have searched various journals but have not found one yet.

Comment: Which part of backpropagation in multi-head attention would you like more understanding on? The answer can then be tailored to that.